# Echoing all values from a MySQL table column

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a database table that looks something like this:

```
User   | Group  
----------------
Bob    | test1  
Susy   | test 1  
Martha | test 2  
Bill   | test 3  
Jake   | test 3
```

I want to output all values from the group column, but repeat none. My goal output is this:

```
test1, test 2, test 3
```

Is there an easy way to do this via PHP?

Answer (score 2):

You have plenty of ways to do this, either pure SQL or PHP. Here are three:

With `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT `Group` FROM Users GROUP BY `Group`
```

With `DISTINCT:`

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Group` FROM Users
```

Using [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) native php method

*By the way, don't use reserved sql keywords as column or table names.*

Answer (score 1):

the key is that the SQL command should contain the DISTINCT keyword:

```
select distinct group from tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

You could import the read values from the MySQL table into a local (php code) based array, then run through the array to see if the value being checked has already been read, if not then echo.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the field from `Group` to something else or you might end up with problems

```
$data = mysql_query("Select distinct Group from table") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{
     echo $row["Group"];
}
```